# Type 'Promise<QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am working on a Firebase project using NextJS and Typescript. I am trying to fetch data from Firestore database and I am getting this error `Type 'Promise<QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

Here is the code that I am using to fetch data from the db

```
const postsRef = collection(db, "discussions");
query(postsRef, orderBy("createdAt"), limit(20));
const [posts]  =  getDocs(postsRef)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getDocs` doesn't return an array which is why you get this error. A `QuerySnapshot` is a custom Firebase type which has `forEach` (similar to an array), but is *not* an array. So you need to iterate through it using the `forEach`:

```js
const postsRef = collection(db, "discussions");
query(postsRef, orderBy("createdAt"), limit(20));
// I'm guessing you need await here too?
const postDocs  =  await getDocs(postsRef)

let posts = []
postDocs.forEach((postDoc) => {
  posts = [...posts, {
    ...postDoc.data(),
    id: postDoc.id,
  }]
})
```

Comment: I have pasted the code and I am getting this error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: That's not related to this code. This new error is a react error stating that you're trying to pass a promise or object as a react component but you can't do that. Either way, that's a new issue you should ask about and you'll need to post more code because it's not related to the Firebase code you posted (not directly at least - some of your React code is needed to debug that)

Comment: @I'mJoeToo Sounds like OP is adding this code inline in their component instead of wrapping it in a `useEffect`/`useAsync`/`useAsyncEffect`.