# Map not working in an array but for each is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react website where I am using firebase cloud firestore. This is the code which I am currently using(according to the docs):

```
async function onTypeSelected(type = "Electronics") {
  var querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, type))
  console.log(querySnapshot)
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data())
  })
}
```

This code is working perfectly. I am able to see the output in the console:

[image: react_error]

However if I use `.map()` method I am getting an error:

```
async function onTypeSelected(type = "Electronics") {
  var querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, type))
  console.log(querySnapshot)
  var a = querySnapshot.map(
    (doc) => {
      return <Card data={doc.data()} />
    }
  )

  console.log(a)
}
```

`<Card />` is another component which I created by myself:

```
function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className='main__container__card'>
      <img src={props.image} />
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
      <hr />
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }} />
      <h2>{props.price}</h2>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }} />
      <hr />
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }} />
      <div className='main__container__card__btn'>
        <CurrentQuantity />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Error:

[image: react_error]

What is the error here?

Please comment if more information is needed.

Comment: Your `querySnapshot` variable is an object instead of an array, that's why you can't use `map`

Comment: What type of data does `getDocs` return?

Comment: I believe this is happening because querySnapshot is an Object and not an Array. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: The `querySnapshot` is object like `{{...}, {...}}` so you can not iterate with map function.

Comment: Ordinary objects don't have `forEach`, guys. The return type is array-like, at least.

Comment: @yabadabaduhast: `{{...}, {...}}` isn't valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `getDocs` isn't returning an `Array`, but something array-like that happens to have `forEach`.

There's a good chance you could destructure it into an array,
Try this:

```
var a = [...querySnapshot].map((doc) => {
  return <Card data={doc.data()} />
});
```

Or, as [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714845/map-not-working-in-an-array-but-for-each-is-working/72714884#comment128439977_72714884), [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
var a = Array.from(querySnapshot, (doc) => {
  return <Card data={doc.data()} />
});
```

Comment: Even better chance if you do `Array.from(querySnapshot)` instead. That will handle an iterable (as the spread above does) *and* any array-like. Even better, since `Array.from` has a mapping function built-in, you get one pass: `const a = Array.from(querySnapshot, (doc) => /*...*/);`

Comment: Cool, I never think of `Array.from`, thanks!

Comment: I used to **constantly** forget about its mapping function. :-)

Comment: Might be worth it to point out that, according to the Firebase Documentation, QuerySnapshot has a property called `docs` that retrieves an Array.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshot_class

Comment: @JoseNuno oh if that’s the case, that deserves a answer 

Comment: @Cerbrus The question got closed so I decided to comment here :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't going to work because a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69713260/5648954) is not iterable nor does it have a `length` property. Using the `.docs` property is the way to get an array as shown in the duplicate link: [Map items of collection snapshot in Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46614055)

Comment: @Cerbrus, so you are saying that `querySnapshot` has an inbuit method called `forEach()`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, @Cerbrus The `Array.from()` and array de-structuring methods aren't working. I am getting an empty array even though my database contains data

Comment: @AdityaDixit - It was worth a try. Sounds like you'll have to fall back on `const a = []; querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { a.push(<Card data={doc.data()} />); });`